# How jQuery implement animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-ui

Does jQuery rely on applying a CSS class to a certain DOM element to apply an animation such as drag and drop, resizing, etc.?

Comment: i dont agree this close call cause i think its pretty obvious question. Maybe it doesnt fit in stackoverflow and needs to be redirected to the other Q&A sites but its a good question and for the answer please check this link:  http://blog.bigbinary.com/2010/01/25/how-animate-really-works-in-jquery-simple-animation-case-discussed.html

Comment: Build up 3000 + reputation and vote to reopen.

Comment: Thanks Berker, most high rept. users use their powers carelessly if u ask me :)

Comment: @BerkerYüceer please add yours as an Answer

Comment: @FateZero this question is closed so i cant no matter how much i want..

Comment: @Floradu88 thanks for reminding.. that is actually why i commented cause i am not getting 3000 rep anytime sooner.

Comment: @FateZero also i dont agree "most high rept. users use their powers carelessly if u ask me" its not true they do their best to keep stackoverflow clean and usefull. They have quite many reasons to close this question but as i said redirecting the question would be a better choise cause in my opinion its not really a bad question just doesnt fit here.

Comment: @BerkerYüceer thanks anyway, i found your link very helpful, I wish I could explore the issue more with other users, but apparently its not gonna be here :) 

IRC it will be then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) :

The .animate() method allows us to create animation effects on any numeric `CSS property`. The only required `parameter` is a plain object of `CSS` properties.

And here I found the method [definition](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp) That what inside happens.

Comment: so jQuery javascript code don't have anything special that can deliver such a result without needing CSS?

Comment: By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be moved.To move them you have to change their css propertie position